# adcli and sssd behavior

Tags: active-directory, sssd

I used to observe a ton of these messages on my domain machine. It seems after rebooting or restarting sssd, it would be normal and given time, it would start forking more and more processes and my suspicion is that it would start to slow down authentication somehow.

> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sssd/sssd_be --domain domain.example.com --uid 0 --gid 0 --debug-to-files

After some research, I added `ldap_referrals = false` in sssd.conf but the forking continued.

After that, I proceeded to install adcli and the forking seems to have stopped.
I would like to ask if anyone can explain the above and confirm if adcli actually fixes it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You hit upstream bug https://pagure.io/SSSD/sssd/issue/3016. It's quite an old one, so perhaps you should consider upgrading..

Comment: thank you for your response. I was reading your blogs on sssd and the backend processes. From the bug description,  it does seem like installing adcli terminates the fork. Please excuse but can sssd be upgraded pretty simply without much fuss?